# Import a URI to a sql field

Tags: sql-server-2008

I storing html to a text field. The html is a fully formed webpage and is stored on my server. I'm frequently updating this field. Currently, after updating the content (using Dreamweaver) and then validating that layout is correct in my browser, I'm manually pasting the HTML to a SSMS query. It'd be easier execute:

update template set myhtmlBody = myFileName

where myfileName resolves either to an http address or an absolute path on the SQLServer's box.

possible?

thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, [looks possible](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/the-tsql-of-text-files/) but difficult.